# Is git(lab) possible to provide access token without modifying the clone URL?

Tags: git, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to clone a repository in a helm chart like:

```
        - name: clone-repo
          image: alpine/git
          command: ['sh', '-c', 'cd /init-data; git clone --branch ${git_branch} ${repo_url} .; rm -rf .git; ls; chmod -R 777 /init-data']
          env:
            - name: repo_url
              value: {{ .Values.git.repoUrl }}
            - name: git_branch
              value: {{ .Values.git.branch | quote }}
            - name: git_token
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: gitlab-bot
                  key: git-token
```

My problem is I don't know how to pass the `git_token` (of GitLab) to git command. I know I can use like `http://<token>@<path>` format, but it requires string modification and I currently don't know how to do it in a helm chart.

Is it an argument like `--username` or `--password` for `git` command so I can pass the access token into?

Comment: Is this related to https://github.com/helm/chart-releaser/issues/14#issuecomment-577045042 ?

Comment: I think no. It's the same problem in another place, and this issue has a script to modify the URL.

Comment: OK. I mentioned it just in case it could give some clues which could help in your particular case.